# run tensorflow on ssh

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and ssh. I want to run a tensorflow model that I just build on my university's server using ssh since I need to use the gpu to speed up the training. I want to ask if this requires the server having the tensorflow package preinstalled or not. The operating system I am using is macos.

Answer (score 0):

In short Yes. You can not train your model on a remote server if the server itself doesn't have TensorFlow installed. You can think of it as remote(your machine) and television(remote server).

Comment: Including python version and tensorflow version? Isn't there some way to make my computer to regard the gpu in the server as a local gpu?

Comment: @Emilio there isn't, and if it was you probably wouldn't want to use it due to the low bandwidth connecting to the "remote gpu".

Comment: @EmilioLiu I found this article on medium that might be useful to you https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/work-remotely-with-pycharm-tensorflow-and-ssh-c60564be862d

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the required packages. You should be able to do this with pip. Try the following command on the server:

```
pip install --user tensorflow
```

You can install pip using get-pip.py as described here:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Quick recipe:

```
#Gettin get-pip
wget -P ~/.local/lib https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python ~/.local/lib/get-pip.py --user 
#Adds /.local/bin to the global path variable and adds it to bashrc file
printf "\nPATH=~/.local/bin/:\$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc 
#run bashrc, almost same effect as restarting terminal
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: the problem is that we do not have pip installed in my university's server.

Comment: You can install pip using get-pip.py, see edit above.